# Problemas para exibir dados com Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá.

Estou com dificuldades de fazer com que cada vez que o usuário clicar em um botão diferente no meu formulário ele execute um Ajax. Se eu colocar o Ajax fora do meu `$('button')` ele exibe na pagina perfeitamente, listar todas as lojas funcionou perfeitamente como coloquei no código comentado, porém ao clicar em um botão submit ele deve trocar de acordo com o botão os dados das minhas tabelas.

Segue o HTML

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="../libs/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="../libs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="../libs/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../libs/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../libs/css/lojas/lojas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="../libs/js/lojas/lojas-json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- header -->
        <header class="row">
            <!-- div menu -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form id="form_lojas" name="form_lojas" method="POST" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar...">
                        <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn form-control " aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>

                        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="form-control" aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda" >Atualizar</button>
                        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="form-control" name="rs" aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda">Rio Grande Do Sul</button>
                        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="form-control" name="sc" aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda">Santa Catarina</button>
                        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="form-control" name="pr" aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda">Paraná</button>
                        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="form-control" aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda">
                            Download Lojas
                        </button>
                        <button id="btn" type="submit" class="form-control"  aria-label="Alinhar na esquerda">
                            Download Regionais
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- end menu -->
        </header>

        <!-- conteudo principal -->
        <aside class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="content-tables" class="col-md-10">


                </div>
            </div> 
        </aside>

        <!-- rodapé-->
        <footer class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </footer>


    </body>
</html>
```

Segue o JS:

```
var url = "http://localhost/nossas_filiais2.0/app/controller/LojaController.php?get=";
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* aki funciona se eu colocar a requisição ajax fora do $('button')
     $.ajax({
            url:url+'select_lojas',
            method: "GET", 
            success: function (data) { 
     */
    $('button').click(function () {
        var jacao = $(this).html();
        switch (jacao) {
            case 'Atualizar':
                //nao fiz ainda
                break;
            case 'Rio Grande Do Sul':
                option = url+'select_lojas_rs';
                break;
            case 'Santa Catarina':
                option = url+'select_lojas_sc';
                break;
            case 'Paraná':
                option = url+'select_lojas_pr';
                break;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:option,
            method: "GET", 
            success: function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var tabela_loja = '';
                    //Tabela visualizada pelo usuario
                    tabela_loja += ' <table id="tabela-loja" class="table table-striped">';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr id="tr-menu">';
                    tabela_loja += '<th>';
                    tabela_loja += '<button id="btn-ver-mais">';
                    tabela_loja += '<span id="span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>';
                    tabela_loja += '</button>';
                    tabela_loja += '</th>';
                    tabela_loja += '<th> Filial: ' + data[i].loja + ' - ' + data[i].sigla + ' - ' + data[i].cidade + ' - ' + data[i].uf + ' </th>';
                    tabela_loja += '<th> Gerente: ' + data[i].gerente + '</th>';
                    tabela_loja += '<th> Fixo: (' + data[i].ddd + ')' + data[i].telefone + '</th>';
                    tabela_loja += '<th> Ramal: ' + data[i].codigo + '</th>';
                    tabela_loja += '<th> Celular: ' + data[i].celular + '</th>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '</table>';
                    //Tabela dropdown display:none por default
                    tabela_loja += '<table id="drop-table">';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<img src="http://www.portal.qq/wp-content/uploads/imagens_lojas/' + data[i].loja + '.jpg"></br>';
                    tabela_loja += '<p id="rodape-img">';
                    tabela_loja += '</p>';
                    tabela_loja += '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<table id="table-info" class="table table-striped">';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Regiao:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].regiao + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Filial:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].loja + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Gerente:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].gerente + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Endereço:</></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].endereco + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>CEP:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].cep + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>CNPJ:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].cnpj + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Inscrição Estadual:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].insc_estadual + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Inscrição Municipal:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].insc_municipal + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Telefone:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + '( ' + data[i].ddd + ' )' + data[i].telefone + '<b> Ramal: </b>' + data[i].codigo + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Celular da Loja:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].celular + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Celular do Gerente:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].celular_gerente + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Celular Corporativo:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].celular_corp + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Porte de Loja:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].tipo + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Data de Inauguração:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td>' + data[i].data_inaug + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Horario de Funcionamento:</b></td>';
                    tabela_loja += '<td><b>Seg à Sex:</b>' + data[i].manha_segsex + ' - ' + data[i].tarde_segsex + ' <b>sab: </b>' + data[i].manha_sab + ' - ' + data[i].tarde_sab + '</td>';
                    tabela_loja += '</tr>';
                    tabela_loja += '</table>';
                    i++;
                    $('#content-tables').append(tabela_loja);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
header('Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
require '../model/Database.php';
require '../model/Loja.php';

class LojaController {

    private $loja;

    function __construct() {
        $this->loja = new Loja();

        //requisições get
        if ($_GET['get']) {
            switch ($_GET['get']) {
                case 'select_lojas':
                    $this->select_lojas();
                    break;
                case 'select_lojas_rs':
                    $this->select_lojas_rs();
                    break;
                case 'select_lojas_sc':
                    $this->select_lojas_sc();
                    break;
                case 'select_lojas_pr':
                    $this->select_lojas_pr();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //lista todas as lojas
    function select_lojas() {
        $pdo = Database::conexao();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM view_listar_lojas_completa');
        $stmt->execute();
        echo json_encode($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

    }
    //lista as filiais de RS
    function select_lojas_rs() {
        $pdo = Database::conexao();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM view_listar_lojas_completa_rs');
        $stmt->execute();
        echo json_encode($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
    }
    //Lista filiais SC
    function select_lojas_sc() {
        $pdo = Database::conexao();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM view_listar_lojas_completa_sc');
        $stmt->execute();
        echo json_encode($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
    }
    //Lista filiais PR
    function select_lojas_pr() {
        $pdo = Database::conexao();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM view_listar_lojas_completa_pr');
        $stmt->execute();
        echo json_encode($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
    }

}
new LojaController();
```

Comment: Inicialize a variável option junto com a url e verifique se o valor dela esta chegando no ajax utilizando console.log(option);

Comment: Como Wictor Chaves falou, verifique a variável option, a inicialização dela não foi colocada no código, acredito ser ela o seu problema principal. Provavelmente ela esta como undefined no momento de realizar a requisição ajax.